# Is multivariate linear regression correct in this case?

Tags: regression, classification, mixed-model, mixture-distribution

I have 20 items rated on 25 different dimensions. These items can be classified in two ways. They belong to Group A or B; also, orthogonally, they belong to Groups W, X, Y or Z. Items were rated by ~ 30 different people.

What I want to know is which dimensions Groups A and B differ on; also, on which dimensions Groups W, X, Y and Z differ on.

I am hoping to conduct the analysis at the trial level (i.e., a trial would entail a single participant's rating of a single item, on all 25 dimensions). So whatever analysis method I choose would have to be able to include random subject and item effects.

What comes to mind is multivariate linear regression: having each of the 25 dimensions be a separate DV, and use group membership to predict them. Does that make sense? Is there a type of mixture model that would be superior to this?

Comment: Maybe some form of multilevel discriminant analysis, separately for A/B and W/X/Y/Z?

Comment: Am I correct that this would essentially reverse the IVs and DVs as they would be set up for multivariate linear regression? Is there an advantage to having group membership be the DV as opposed to the IV?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought the nominal variables were logically the DVs, but it looks like the other way around.

I think multivariate regression makes sense for your question. If you wanted to do data reduction first, you could also do a mixture or cluster model on your 25 dimensions and predict class membership from your IVs in a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the feedback! I've been running into an issue of not being able to model crossed random subject and item variables when doing dimension reduction on the 25 dimensions. Do you know of a way to do that with mixture or cluster modeling?

Comment: That sounds computationally...intense. How many respondents do you have?

Comment: Yeah, when trying to run an MFA it's failed with even one grouping factor. I have roughly 45 participants who each rated 15/20 items. So 900 individual observations.

Comment: If you treat the items as "subjects" nested within respondents, I think you could do without the item random effect, especially since a given item always has the same levels of the predictors. That should make it reasonably straightforward.